# How to display my database in real time (Php, js, jquery, AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to know how to display my database (mysql) in **real time without sending too many queries** to my database to **not overload it**.
I know that it is necessary to use Ajax for that but I don't know how to use it correctly.

For **now I use JQuery with the load function** to do this, can you give me your opinion and tell me how to do if this isn't the best solution(i know it's not), thank you!

Resume of my question:

**How to display a mysql database in real time using php and ajax ? For example if I add a new order in my database i want to display it without refreshing my webpage.**

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>MGT Orders</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.10.0/css/tachyons.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    section {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    }


    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .container > div {
        flex: 100%;
    }

    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
        /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
        .container > div {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    @supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
        /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
        .container > div {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    @keyframes marquee {
        0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
        100% { transform: translate(0, -50%); }
    }


</style>
</head>
<body class="bg-light-gray">    
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="tc fl f2-ns f3 pv2 b">Orders <span class="green">Created</span></div>
                <div class="tc fl f4-ns pv2" id="ordersCreated"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="container bt b--black">
                <div class="tc fl f2-ns f3 pt2 b ">Orders To <span class="yellow">Pick</span> </div>
                <div class="tc fl f4-ns f5 ">Orders to <span class="orange">Ship</span> today in orange</div>
                <div class="tc fl f4-ns f5 pb2  red">Late Orders in red</div>
                <div class="tc fl f4-ns pv2 " id="ordersToPick"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container bt b--black">
                <div class="tc fl f2-ns f3 pv2 b">Orders  <span class="blue">Invoiced</span></div>
                <div class="tc fl f4-ns pv2 " id="ordersInvoiced"> </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval('load_orders()', 500);
        function load_orders() {
            $('#ordersCreated').load('queryOrdersCreated.php');
            $('#ordersToPick').load('queryOrdersToPick.php');
            //$('#ordersToShip').load('queryOrdersToShip.php');
            $('#ordersInvoiced').load('queryOrdersInvoiced.php');

            if ($("body").height() > screen.height) {
                $("article").css("animation", "marquee 50s linear infinite" );
            }
            else {
                $("article").removeAttr('style');
            }

            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
                $("article").removeAttr('style');
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Php page for my connection to the database: (connect_db.php)

```
<?php

$db_name = 'warehouseproject';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}
?>
```

One of php my page with some queries (queryOrdersToPick.php):

```
<?php
//header("Refresh:1");
include('connect_db.php');

$sqlPick = 'SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `State`= "Open" AND `Reserved` > 0 AND `Invoice` = "" AND `Ship Date` > date_format(CURRENT_DATE(), "%m/%d/%Y") ORDER BY `Reserved` DESC';
$sqlPickShip = 'SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `State`= "Open" AND `Reserved` > 0 AND `Invoice` = "" AND `Ship Date`= date_format(CURRENT_DATE(), "%m/%d/%Y") ORDER BY `Reserved` DESC';
$sqlLatePickShip = 'SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `State`= "Open" AND `Reserved` > 0 AND `Invoice` = "" AND `Ship Date` < date_format(CURRENT_DATE(), "%m/%d/%Y") ORDER BY `Reserved` DESC';

$queryPick = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlPick);
$queryPickShip = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlPickShip);
$queryLatePickShip = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlLatePickShip);


if (!$queryPickShip || !$queryPick || !$queryLatePickShip) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

$noLatePickShip = 0;
while ($rowLatePickShip = mysqli_fetch_array($queryLatePickShip))
{
    echo    '<div class="pa2 bg-red ba b--white br-pill"> SO <b>'.$rowLatePickShip['SO'].'</b> 
                <div>'.$rowLatePickShip['Reserved'].' Items</div> </div> '/*
                ---- Ship date: <b>'. date('m/d/Y', strtotime($rowLatePickShip['Ship Date'])) 
            .'</b></div>'*/;

    $noLatePickShip++;
}

$noPickShip = 0;
while ($rowPickShip = mysqli_fetch_array($queryPickShip))
{
    echo    '<div class="pa2 bg-orange ba b--white br-pill"> SO <b>'.$rowPickShip['SO'].'</b> 
            <div>'.$rowPickShip['Reserved'].' Items</div> </div> '/*

                <b>'.$rowPickShip['Reserved'].'</b> </div> '/*
                ---- Ship date: <b>'. date('m/d/Y', strtotime($rowPickShip['Ship Date'])) 
            .'</b></div>'*/;

    $noPickShip++;
}

$noPick = 0;
while ($rowPick = mysqli_fetch_array($queryPick))
{
    echo    '<div class="pa2 bg-gold ba b--white br-pill"> SO <b>'.$rowPick['SO'].'</b> 
            <div>'.$rowPick['Reserved'].' Items</div> </div> '/*

                <b>'.$rowPick['Reserved'].'</b> </div> '/*
                ---- Ship date: <b>'. date('m/d/Y', strtotime($rowPick['Ship Date'])) 
            .'</b></div>'*/;

    $noPick++;
}

$totalPick = $noLatePickShip + $noPick + $noPickShip;
?>
```

Comment: Your question is really quite broad. Try breaking it down in smaller, simpler questions so we can help.

Comment: @TheImpaler hmmm ok.. so my question is how to display a mysql database in real time using php and ajax ?
For example if I add a new order in my database i want to display it without refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timestamp to the orders, modify it on update and only request the orders with a higher timestamp as your last request.

```
ALTER TABLE `orders`
ADD COLUMN `lastmodified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Yes it can be a solution but it's not the best thing to do I think, but thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're right to question [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) your DB; that would be needlessly expensive. Instead, I recommend:

1. Using [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
2. Initially querying for *ALL* of the data
3. Broadcast [patches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(computing)) to the client when the DB is modified.

This should be easy, if your [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) handlers dispatch, directly or indirectly, the patch.

Example:

1. Client initially loads page

   - client requests ALL data
   - client connects to WebSocket

     - client has WebSocket message handlers to update view when a patch is received
2. Server sends all data to client

   - on any CRUD operation to the DB, broadcast a message, to the client, i.e.:
     `{ op: DELETE, rsrc: USER_TABLE, data }` (`DELETE` and `USER_TABLE` are enums).

At the infrastructure / data level, you have *a lot* of options:

1. cache eager-loaded data or lazy-load it
2. queue patches
3. use [protobufs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) (binary messaging)
4. [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) your data to reduce payload sizes
5. [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) and [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) support

[Server push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) propagation (via [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or WebSockets), caching, [queueing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)), and [lazy-loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) will be your friends for this.

Comment: Ok thanks ! And have you got some good tutorials to use sockets with php ?

Comment: When I programmed in PHP, I used [Ratchet,](http://socketo.me/) but that may be overkill for your app. It doesn't sound like you *need* bi-directional comm.; you might only need server push. What is your app server running, laravel?

Comment: No i don't use any framework, i just code in php using a wamp server